# How to find the moment generating function of this distribution

Tags: probability

If $f(x) = 0.5 e^{-|x|}$ for $-\infty < x < \infty$, how would you find the moment generating function for this? Also how would you find the distribution of $Y = |X|$?

Attempt:

$$E(e^{tX}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{tx} \; dx.$$

Comment: Hint: continue your attempt, separating the integral into an integral on $x\lt0$, where $f(x)=\frac12\mathrm e^x$, and an integral on $x\gt0$, where $f(x)=\frac12\mathrm e^{-x}$.

Comment: I get (1/(t-1))*(e^infinity -1) when x is positive. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The pdf doesn't integrate to one. I think there is a .5 in the exponential term.

Answer (score 4):

As Didier Piau stated:
$$
\begin{align}
E(e^{tX}) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{tx} \ dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) e^{tx}\ dx+\int_0^\infty f(x) e^{tx}\ dx \\  \\
& =\int_{-\infty}^0 0.5e^x e^{tx}\ dx + \int_0^\infty 0.5 e^{-x} e^{tx}\ dx \\  \\
&  = 0.5\left(\int_{-\infty}^0  e^{(t+1)x}\ dx+\int_{0}^\infty e^{(t-1)x} \ dx\right) = \frac{0.5}{t+1}-\frac{0.5}{t-1},\quad t\in (-1,1)
\end{align}
$$

For the distribution of $Y=|X|$ we have the general rule for a transformation of the form $y=h(x)$ in our case $Y=|X|$ with $Y\in [0,+\infty)$: $g(y)=f(h^{-1}(y))|\frac{d(h^{-1}(y))}{dy}|$. Applying this rule to your problem will give you the distribution of Y.

Comment: One can simplify $E(\mathrm e^{tX})$ to $1/(1-t^2)$.