# Finding the mgf of $f_X(x) =e^{−2|x|}I_{(−\infty,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

> Give the mgf of a random variable having pdf $$f_X(x)
>  =e^{−2|x|}I_{(−\infty,\infty)}(x)$$

I found a very similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114426/how-to-find-the-moment-generating-function-of-this-distribution) but I wanted to make sure I'm applying it correctly:

$$
\begin{align}
M_X(t)
&=\operatorname E(e^{tX}) \\\\
& =\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) e^{tx}\ dx + \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{tx}\ dx\\\\
& =\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2x} e^{tx}\ dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-2x} e^{tx}\ dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{t+2}+\frac{1}{2-t}
\end{align}
$$

Following the pattern in the problem I referenced, would the support of $t$ be from $(-2,2)$? If so, what is the reasoning for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the word *support* except when talking about the closure of the subset of the domain on which the function is not zero, or a related concept also yielding a closed set.

However, the **domain** of $M_X(t) = \operatorname E(e^{tX})$ is the set of values of $t$ for which $\operatorname E(|e^{tX}|)<+\infty,$ and since $t$ and $X$ are real, and the function $e^s$ is positive for all $s\in\mathbb R,$ that's the same as the set of values of $t$ for which $\operatorname E(e^{tX})<+\infty.$ If $t\ge2$ then
$$
\int e^{-2s} e^{tx} \,dx = +\infty
$$
and similarly the integral over the negative half-line is $+\infty$ if $t\le-2.$ So the domain of $M_X$ is the open interval $(-2,2).$